# Does signalr create connection for each hub inside same app or all the hubs share same connection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

If the answer is each hub has its own connection , how expensive are really these connections, lets say we have 3 hubs for 30K user connected is there really a performance gain if I reduce them to one hub ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From docs :](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

> Each connection object that you create encapsulates information about
>   a connection to a SignalR service that contains one **or more** Hub
>   classes. To communicate with a Hub class, you use a proxy object which
>   you create yourself (if you're not using the generated proxy) or which
>   is generated for you.

[Also](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs)

> All clients will use the same URL to establish a SignalR connection
>   with your service ("/signalr" or your custom URL if you specified
>   one), and that connection is used for **all** Hubs defined by the service.

Comment: Thanks man , I read many sources but there was no clear answer